# How to Crop Image from Gallery with a Fixed Size

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

When a user picks a photo from gallery, I want them to be able to crop it.  However,  I want the scaling to be a fixed box (square) at all times.  Equal length and equal width.

I thought adding something like this to my intent would do it, but no:

```
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Realized what I needed:

```
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
```

Comment: i have to add  photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");